# my bot.wait_for is not returning a message but the check im using works for other code

Tags: python, discord.py

i wish ask a question, add two reactions to the message and if they responde with a certain reaction il do something  and if they responde with the other one, then il do something else, but the wait for im using is not returning anything and its like it doesnt accept any input

ive tried a check that checks if its a private channel and if the author is the user but that was originally for message wait fors, so i stopped using it and used a reaction check from someone here in stack overflow and that doesnt work either

```
        if seq is None:
            return ()
        if isinstance(seq, Sequence) and not isinstance(seq, str):
            return seq
        else:
            return (seq,)

    def reaction_check(message=None, emoji=None, author=None, ignore_bot=True):
        message = make_sequence(message)
        message = tuple(m.id for m in message)
        emoji = make_sequence(emoji)
        author = make_sequence(author)
        def check(reaction, user):
            if ignore_bot and user.bot:
                return False
            if message and reaction.message.id not in message:
                return False
            if emoji and reaction.emoji not in emoji:
                return False
            if author and user not in author:
                return False
            return True
        return check


    servmsg = await user.send("**Which Server Were You Banned From（React Below)**")
    await servmsg.add_reaction("<:playroom:553266953335341056>")
    await servmsg.add_reaction("<:finesse:553266956149719050>")
    print("owo1")
    def check(m):
        return isinstance(m.channel, discord.abc.PrivateChannel) and m.author.id == user.id
    print("owo hello")
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("add_reaction", check=reaction_check(message=servmsg, author=user), timeout=500.00) 
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await user.send("You Have Ran Out Of Time")
    print("reaction waitfor works")
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:finesse:553266956149719050>":
```

i get no errors but i want it to check if the emoji used is at least a one of two emojis

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for `"reaction_add"`, not `"add_reaction"`.  The argument to `wait_for` is based on the name of the event: [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)